# Alias with pipe to w3m doesn't work

Tags: linux, bash, alias

I'm trying to make custom bash alias for md files viewing

```
alias mdprnt='pandoc $1 | w3m -T text/html'
# Custom user funtions
mdless(){
    pandoc $1 | w3m -T text/html
}
```

Appears that function is working correctly and displaying formatted html.
But instead alias shows not completely formatted text.
I understand that it is better to use function in this case, but still why this strange behavior with alias?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- alias is not a fonction, so no positional parameter ($1)
- `help -m alias`: an alias needs a value, so no variable

nota: to allow the variable expansion, you must use double quote